# Getting Error When Converting from Decimal to Double in C#

Tags: c#, calculator

I got an error and I don't know why. I dont find the need to convert to double or am i supposed to to that? I am really confused right now

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'double'

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.Write("speed: ");
        string speed = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Gammafaktor: ");
        string Gammafaktor = Console.ReadLine();


        {
        }
        var gamma1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Gammafaktor);
        var speed1 = Convert.ToDecimal(speed);

        if ( speed1 !=0 )
        {

            var calc = 1m / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Sqrt(1 - speed1 * speed1));
            Console.WriteLine(calc);
        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: For future reference - use `double` for continuous measurements (like speed) and `decimal` for discrete measurements (like money).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely seeing:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'double'

on the line with the `Math.Sqrt` call, or (if you move the assignment out to a local):

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

`Math.Sqrt` takes a `double`, not a `decimal`, and the conversion from `decimal` to `double` is *explicit*, not *implicit* - meaning it isn't going to just do it automatically without you knowing about it; so:

```
var calc = 1m / Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Sqrt((double)(1 - speed1 * speed1)));
```

As a side note... that calculation looks very odd (and dangerous), unless `speed1` is always between zero and one.